# How to return number of rows inserted each month from SQL using EF C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a customers table and I want to return count of rows inserted each month or Customers registered each month. The following code returns only month and record count but I want to record 0 if say for Jan no customers where registered. Thank you.

The following code returns:

```
Month 2   Count 15
Month 5   Count 11
Month 9   Count 82
```

I also want to return

```
Month 1 count 0
Month 3 count 0
so on..
```

My code:

```
var query = (from customers in context.customers 
             group customers by customers.RegisterDateTime.Month into g 
             select new
                    { Month = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }
            ).ToList();

foreach (var data in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Month "+ data.Month +"  Count "+ data.Count);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = (from m in Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
             join c in context.customers on m equals c.RegisteredDateTime.Month into monthGroup
             select new { Month = m, Count = monthGroup.Count() }
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you. so if i have a one to many relationship table , customer to many orders in order table. in orders table I want unique item names as count but the date property is in customers table. How can I do that to get same results as you answered. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want the range from the lowest month and the highest month.

I see no possiblity (but maybe there is?) to do it inside your query directly. I would add the "0" after the query to fill  the gaps between the range with zeros.

So I would add the following code line after your query:

```
        var lowestKey = result.Min(x => x.Month);
        var highestKey = result.Max(x => x.Month);       

        query = query.Union(
            Enumerable.Range(lowestKey, highestKey - lowestKey)
            .Where(e => !result.Any(r => r.Month == e))
            .Select(s => new { Month = s, Count = 0 })
            ).OrderBy(o => o.Month).ToList();
```

Since I don't have your complete code, this query maybe need some adjustment.

If you need another range, than you can simple change it.

My complete example look like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Initialize the list
        var result = new []
        {
            new  { Month = 2, Count = 15 },
            new  { Month = 5, Count = 11 },
            new  { Month = 9, Count = 82 }
        }.ToList();

        // Generate a List with 0 in Range
        var lowestKey = result.Min(x => x.Month);
        var highestKey = result.Max(x => x.Month);          

        result = result.Union(
            Enumerable.Range(lowestKey, highestKey - lowestKey)
            .Where(e => !result.Any(r => r.Month == e))
            .Select(s => new  { Month = s, Count = 0 })
            ).OrderBy(o => o.Month).ToList();


        foreach (var data in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Month " + data.Month + "  Count " + data.Count);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , It is a SQL DB table customers , Just want to return count of customers registered each month Like January or as month 01   , 3 records/customers March  4 records , May 0 records

Comment: If you always have the 12 month from January to December, you may change my code Line with the Enumarble.Range to Enumerable.Range(1, 12)

Comment: hwo can i replace the data source var result = new []
        {
            new  { Month = 2, Count = 15 },
            new  { Month = 5, Count = 11 },
            new  { Month = 9, Count = 82 }
        }.ToList(); to   SQL List of customers

Comment: I think, that Wonder Boy now provided you an better solution. It seems really nice :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps,

```
var query = (from customers in context.customers 
         group customers by customers.RegisterDateTime.Month into g 
         select new
                { Month = g.Key, Count = g.Count(x=>x!=null) }
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: It doesnt change anything, same result